# Agregar o quitar propiedades de anguar en un input de un Form en angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Cordial saludo:

Estoy aprendiendo angular y tengo un formulario:

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
```

Y este seria el HTML

```
un form con varios input

<ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.get('numberVisaField')">
    <div class="ui-form_group">
        <ibe-input
            [isRequired]="formControlIsRequired('numberVisaField')"
            [id]="'IDVISA'"
            [name]="'NAME'">
        </ibe-input>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Este es un ejemplo de input:

Mi pregunta es:

"Existe alguna manera de eliminar o agregar las propiedades que estan adentro de [] mediante el .ts" ????

Agradecería su ayuda

Comment: Que sería `[]`?

Comment: Cuando una variable se llama desde el .ts y no es modificable... a nivel de backend exite pero desde fronted no puede ser modificada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A que te refieres con eliminar? Si tu pregunta es si puedes modificar un valor de una propiedad que le pasaste a un componente hijo desde el padre puedes hacerlo de varias formas:

1. Viewchild: Con Viewchild podes obtener la referencia al componente, y obtener acceso a sus propiedades y métodos.
2. Observable: Podrías pasarle a tu componente hijo un observable, para comunicarte a través del padre y enviarle valores para que modifique las variables.
3. implementar ngOnChanges en el componente hijo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes referenciar el input mediante un viewchild (https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) para acceder a sus propiedades desde tu fichero ts.

Comment: Muchas Gracias :)